# Set multiple values to Enterprise Keywords TaxonomyField

Tags: 2010, development, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I want to programmatically set the values of the `Enterprise Keywords` Managed Metadata field.  This field supports multiple values, but I can only get it to take one at a time.

I have the following method:

```
public void AddKeywords(SPListItem item, string keywordString)
{
    TaxonomyField managedField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(Fields.Keywords) as TaxonomyField;

    if (managedField != null)
    {
        TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(item.Web.Site, false);
        TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[managedField.SspId];
        TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(managedField.TermSetId);

        string[] keywords = keywordString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

        foreach (string keyword in keywords)
        {
            Term keywordTerm;
            if (!termSet.Terms.Any(t => t.Name == keyword))
            {
                keywordTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(keyword, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
                termStore.CommitAll();
            }
            else
            {
                keywordTerm = termSet.Terms[keyword];
            }

            managedField.SetFieldValue(item, keywordTerm);
        }
    }
}
```

After this is executed, only the last keyword is set at the value, overwriting any previous values on this field.

How can I set multiple values to the `Enterprise Keywords` Managed Metadata Field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are setting the value of the field, then overwriting it when your loop gets to the next keyword.

Rather than calling `managedField.SetFieldValue` every time you should be collecting all your terms in some form of collection, then calling it with this overload : [TaxonomyField.SetFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee569052.aspx)

for example

```
    var terms = new List<Term>();

    foreach (string keyword in keywords)
    {
        Term keywordTerm;
        if (!termSet.Terms.Any(t => t.Name == TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(keyword)))
        {
            keywordTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(keyword, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
            termStore.CommitAll();
        }
        else
        {
            keywordTerm = termSet.Terms[keyword];
        }

        terms.Add(keywordTerm);
    }

    managedField.SetFieldValue(item, terms);
```

Another completely unrelated suggestion I would make is call [TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename.aspx) on your keyword before comparing it, or keywords with `&` will complicate things.

Comment: *Facepalm*  I'm not sure how I missed that overload.  Thank you sir!

Comment: I tried the above code, it is working perfectly for multiple values but if i add a new value, the value is overwritten in the enterprise keyword column, it is not adding the value to the existing list. Any suggestions?