# add tags to enterprise keyword column programatically

Tags: document-library, taxonomy

I would like to add tags into the enterprise keywords column of shared docs library programatically. I have seen this link
[Set multiple values to Enterprise Keywords TaxonomyField](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19389/set-multiple-values-to-enterprise-keywords-taxonomyfield)

and as "Fields.Keywords" is not present as per that link, I have used "TaxKeyWord" as shown below..But I am able to store the tag only in the Term Store, they are not getting stored in the listitem of the library...How do I do the storing to the Enterprise Keyword column?

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];
 SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(2);// Id of the document
  string keywordString = "tag1,tag2"; //comma seperated tags

 TaxonomyField managedField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("TaxKeyword") as TaxonomyField;

                        if (managedField != null)
                        {
                            TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(item.Web.Site, false);
                            TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[managedField.SspId];
                            TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(managedField.TermSetId);

                            string[] keywords = keywordString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

                            var terms = new List<Term>();

                            foreach (string keyword in keywords)
                            {
                                Term keywordTerm;
                                if (!termSet.Terms.Any(t => t.Name == TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(keyword)))
                                {
                                    keywordTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(keyword, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
                                    termStore.CommitAll();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    keywordTerm = termSet.Terms[keyword];
                                }

                                terms.Add(keywordTerm);
                            }

                            managedField.SetFieldValue(item, terms);

                        }


                    }
```

Comment: Do you have `item.Update()` anywhere?

Comment: @Per Jakobsen, I have added the modifed snippet with item.Update below, it does not update the column, do check the snippet

Comment: In the snippet you've added `item.SystemUpdate(false)` before the ` managedField.SetFieldValue(item, terms);`. It should be after.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that we use to add terms to the Keyword column:

```
//try to find the tag in the Keywords term store if it does not exist in the "Topics" term set
            if (termCollection == null || termCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                termCollection = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.KeywordsTermSet.GetTerms(termLabel, 1033, true, StringMatchOption.ExactMatch, 100, true);
            }

            //if the term does not exist, create the term and add to the validated list
            if (termCollection != null && termCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                //If we have a one term with an exact match, the add it
                if (validatedTermsList.Count == 1)
                {
                    validatedTermsList.Add(termCollection.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    //if we have multiple terms as a result of the search, try find an exact match for the selected term by matching its GUID
                    var exactMathedTerm = termCollection.Where(t => t.Id == termGUID);
                    if (exactMathedTerm != null && exactMathedTerm.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        //If there is a term matching the guid, then add it, otherwise, add the first one from the result set
                        validatedTermsList.Add(exactMathedTerm.First());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        validatedTermsList.Add(termCollection.First());
                    }
                }
            }
            else //the term does not exist and needs to be created new
            {
                var validatedTerm = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.KeywordsTermSet.CreateTerm(ValidateTermLabel(termLabel), 1033);
                validatedTermsList.Add(validatedTerm);
                isNewTermsAdded = true;
            }
        }

        //if any new term was created commit the changes to the term store
        if (isNewTermsAdded)
        {
            session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore.CommitAll();
        }
```

And here is the code to update our item:

```
  //this is used to decide whether to update the children's topic tagging information or not
            var IsTopicChanged = (values.ToString() != discussionItem["TaxKeyword"].ToString());

            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection newValues = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(String.Empty);
            if (IsTopicChanged)
            {
                var taxonomyFieldValues = GetValidatedTerms(topicTagged).Select((t) => { return t.GetDefaultLabel(1033) + "|" + t.Id.ToString(); });
                newValues.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(String.Join(";", taxonomyFieldValues.ToArray()));

                var taxKeywordField = discussionItem.Fields.GetField("TaxKeyword") as TaxonomyField;
                taxKeywordField.SetFieldValue(discussionItem, newValues);
            }

            discussionItem.Update();
```

Comment: I am trying to add it to the EnterpriseKeyword column..the program already adds to the TermStore\Keyword of the metadata service...I just modified the above code and am manually setting the TaxKeyword column...
<code>
....
 keywordTerm = termSet.Terms[keyword];
item["TaxKeyword"] = "1033;#"+keywordTerm.Name + "|" + keywordTerm.Id.ToString();
terms.Add(keywordTerm);
 }
 item.SystemUpdate(false);
managedField.SetFieldValue(item, terms);

</code>
This doesn't work also to insert into the Enterprise Keyword column.

Comment: sorry could not wrap the code in a code block

Comment: this code doesn't insert the keyword to the manage metadata termstore... is there a way I can insert the keyword from there?